# ISP tricks DNS?

Tags: networking, dns, isp

Running "nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8" yields IPs of my ISP (as Non-authoritative answer). I think this started occurring recently. Probably they are making cache or something, as nearest Google data center is quite far away.

First of all, how is that even possible? I thought the worst they could do is block me from sending a DNS request to 8.8.8.8 (say by blocking remote port 53), but how can they trick 8.8.8.8 from sending me a correct address?

Second, how can I bypass this, if at all?

Thanks

EDIT:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
>
> Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\asdf nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
>
> Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
>
> Address:  8.8.8.8
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>
> Name:    google.com
>
> Addresses:  2a00:1450:4017:801::1006
>
> ```
>      212.199.205.232
>      212.199.205.242
>      212.199.205.222
>      212.199.205.237
>      212.199.205.231
>      212.199.205.241
>      212.199.205.212
>      212.199.205.227
>      212.199.205.247
>      212.199.205.246
>      212.199.205.251
>      212.199.205.221
>      212.199.205.217
>      212.199.205.236
>      212.199.205.226
>      212.199.205.216
> ```
>
> C:\Users\asdf>

And using DNSCrypt (with and without option of DNSCrypt over port 443):

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

> C:\Users\asdf>nslookup google.com
>
> 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa
>
> primary name server = localhost
>
> responsible mail addr = nobody.invalid
>
> serial  = 1
>
> refresh = 600 (10 mins)
>
> retry   = 1200 (20 mins)
>
> expire  = 604800 (7 days)
>
> default TTL = 10800 (3 hours)
>
> Server:  UnKnown
>
> Address:  127.0.0.1
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>
> Name:    google.com
>
> Addresses:  2a00:1450:4017:800::1008
>             212.199.205.242
>             212.199.205.247
>             212.199.205.237
>             212.199.205.232
>             212.199.205.231
>             212.199.205.226
>             212.199.205.217
>             212.199.205.212
>             212.199.205.227
>             212.199.205.241
>             212.199.205.236
>             212.199.205.246
>             212.199.205.216
>             212.199.205.251
>             212.199.205.221
>             212.199.205.222
>
> C:\Users\asdf>

Formatting is a bit off, sorry about that.

Comment: What IPs is it returning? It's actually quite trivial for an ISP to intercept the connection to `8.8.8.8` (or any non-encrypted connection) and inject whatever data they want; However, that kind of hijacking would be *suicide* for an ISP's reputation.

Comment: It returns some of the ISP addresses, the exact IP is not really relevant I guess. This is not the US or western Europe btw, so ISP can do whatever they want without anyone even noticing something is wrong.

Comment: If you remind me how to copy the contents of CMD on Windows, I'll paste the results.

Comment: So you're also saying that if you go to google.com, it redirects to one of the IPs you get returned in your nslookup?  All systems?  One system?  This could easily be a trojan or virus which is redirecting

Comment: http://whois.net/ip-address-lookup/212.199.219.251

Comment: One of the addresses I get, and it's registered to my ISP. I also somehow doubt this trojan would be serving me HD youtube videos from this address (probably acting as a cache). :P

Comment: “remind me how to copy the contents of CMD” –– If you have Quick Edit enabled, just select as you would in any other program, and right-click to copy.  Otherwise, right click -> “Mark”, then select, and (I believe) if you type (Enter) it will copy.

Comment: Are you sure those arn't real IP's of Google's of machines that are co-located near your ISP (or even in your ISP itself if the ISP is a bigger one)?

Comment: Hmm, no I'm not sure. I just tried to nslookup from a third party EU service, www.ping.eu. Also there, it resolved to some IP that doesn't appear to belong to Google. I guess some of these IPs may indeed belong to Google. I was just expecting them to be from Google's known ranges of IPs

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat Like many things, it started happening when someone realized they could use it for their advantage, and nobody made any noise about the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think what you think is hijacking is hijacking (I am not saying it is not happening, just the evidence does not point to it.)

From what it looks like you are just seeing 3rd party location based [CDNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) Google uses for it's servers.

Google would never be able to serve up pages at the speed it offers if every query had to go through a master database back in Mountain View, CA. So they have 1000's of mirrored servers at ISP's all over the world to help serve up content quicker. They do not necessarily manage the servers that are hosting the page, only the software running on the server. Heck it could be done all with [VPS's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server).

So you are likely seeing the IP's belonging to the hosting company/CDN that Google is using for serving pages in your area.

(P.S. The way they are poiting you to the correct CDN (the reason you get a different set of numbers vs `ping.eu`) is the DNS servers sitting on `8.8.8.8` look at the requesting IP and reply with the IPs for the CDN serving that area by doing a [IP Geolocation Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation_software))

Comment: I think that you're probably right, it's the most logical answer at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Do you get the same results when using `8.8.4.4` as a DNS server? `208.67.222.222` ? `208.67.220.220` ?

If your ISP is hijacking connections to `8.8.8.8`, there's not much you can do other than complain to them and connect to `8.8.8.8` over a VPN.

I would very much like to see the DNS report from [NameBench](https://code.google.com/p/namebench/), a DNS testing utility which is primarily used for comparing and finding the fastest DNS server available, but also checks for hijacking. It will tell you if your ISP is doing Bad Things<sup>TM</sup> with your internet.

Comment: Same thing with all of them (I noticed some give slightly different IP addresses still of my ISP, but that may be due to time of day as well). Also, I just now downloaded DNSCrypt, which supposedly combats against hijacking. I even marked for it resolve on port 443. Still same damn thing! I'll paste those results as well momentarily.

Comment: Gah! Just tried it with my phone on cellular network, even here there's a DNS hijack! To different local ISPs addresses, but still...for example one of the addresses: http://whois.net/ip-address-lookup/213.57.24.38 When did this phenomenon start happening...I swear this didn't happen a few years ago

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your ISP is transparently proxying outgoing UDP 53 and forcing it to go their DNS servers.

[If you have Tor running, you can have it resolve DNS queries.](https://techstdout.boum.org/TorDns/)  You'll need to set your local DNS servers to point to the internal IP address on which you are running Tor.

I believe OpenDNS accepts DNS queries on UDP port 5353.  You'll need a locally running proxy that accepts DNS requests on localhost and then redirects them to OpenDNS on port 5353.  Something like [Acrylic DNS Proxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/acrylic/) can be used on Windows.

Comment: Would DNSCrypt ensure what you said above? Because that still didn't help.